# How to comment the whole line with Vim substitute() and &commentstring

Tags: vim, plugins, string-substitution

I've been trying to write a vimscript that reads the output of a shell command (`figlet`) and comments every line of it. I want to use the `&commentstring` variable since I want this script to work with any filetype.

So far I have achieved only inconsistent results. Here is and example:

1. Prompt the user to enter his/her initials and pass that to the shell command `figlet` to print ascii art at the top of the file:

```
let g:initials = input('Authors initials: ')
execute '0r! figlet -W ' . toupper(g:initials)
```

The output is the following (e.g. g:initials = JT):

```
      _   _____ 
     | | |_   _|
  _  | |   | |  
 | |_| |   | |  
  \___/    |_|
```

2. Get the amount of lines of the output:

```
let s:line_count = system("figlet -W " . g:signit_initials . "| wc -l")
```

3. Use the vim function `substitute()` to comment every line:

```
let s:i = 1
while s:i < s:line_count
execute 'silent' . s:i . 's/^.*$/\=substitute(&commentstring, "%s", "\t" . getline(".") . "\t", "")'
let s:i += 1
endwhile
```

The output is the following:

```
/*      _   _____ */
/*     | | |_   _|*/
/*  _  | |   | |  */
/* | |_| |   | |  */
/*  ___/    |_|  */
```

As you can see, it works well until the last line and I dont understand why. Maybe there is a better way to aproach this. Anyways, I would really appriciate if someone would provide me with some help on how to solve this little issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it works well until the last line and I dont understand why

The last line contains a backslash. And it gets modified according to `:h sub-replace-special`. So, at the very least, you must escape it with another one. Sort of `escape(getline('.'), '\')`. However, for this particular case I'd rather go with `printf`, as it looks easier and more natural: `printf(&cms, "\t"..getline(".").."\t")`

Also there's no need for "while" loop, as many commands and functions accept line range: it's both more effective and easier to write.

> Maybe there is a better way to aproach this.

IMO this looks better:

```
call append(0, map(systemlist("figlet -W "..toupper(g:initials)),
    \ {_, v -> printf(&cms, "\t" .. v .. "\t")}))
```

Comment: Printf works perfect! Thank you! Nevertheless I would like to try your suggested solution. It seems more efficient to map trough a list.  However, I dont understand the last line: ```\ {_, v -> printf(&cms, "\t" .. v .. "\t")}))``` Could you maybe explain it?

Comment: @johannesthyssen See `:h lambda`

Comment: got it! Thanks! One last question: Why do you use two dots for concatenation instead of one?

Comment: @JohannesThyssen Both work. But one-dot may be ambiguous. This is why `x . y` is strongly preferred over `x.y`. With two-dots you're free to choose between `x..y` and `x .. y`. See also `:h expr5`.